# ld: library not found for -l:/usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.3.0.0.dylib

Tags: xcode, ld, ros

This is on OS X 10.10.4, using `rosmake` (from the Robot Operating System)

```
ld: library not found for -l:/usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.3.0.0.dylib
```

I'm getting the above error message. I have a feeling the problem is with the colon inserted after the l? /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.3.0.0.dylib absolutely exists.

Comment: How are you specifying the library?  If you simply add it to the link build phase, the naming should be taken care of "automatically".

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm...not. It found it on its own; the CMakeLists.txt doesn't even specify to find OpenCV. I'm investigating this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Yes, the `:` is the issue.

I've no idea what `rosmake` is, but the linker will want a `-L` option, specifying the library path, and a `-l` option, specifying the library:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_xphoto
```

You normally only use `-l/usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.3.0.0.dylib` if you want to disambiguate between `.a` and `.dylib` files.  If you don't then use both `-L` and `-l`.